# (Code review) Copying file path relative to cwd with the line number appended

Tags: neovim, functions, register, cursor, lua

I am replicating what PHPStorm and VSCode do by allowing me to copy the file path and line number (plus column) to clipboard. I have written a function in lua to do this, but, I wanted to ask about best practices and to get opinions on whether I did it "the right way". It's just for my own knowledge, what I have is working perfectly well, at the moment at least.

```lua
function M.yank_file_path()
  local current_file = vim.fn.expand("%:r")
  local extension = vim.fn.expand("%:e")
  local current_line = vim.fn.line(".")
  return current_file .. "." .. extension .. ":" .. current_line
end
```

All that's left is to figure out how to copy it into the system clipboard, but, I'll figure that out tomorrow.

Comment: Do you use lua, because you want to improve your lua skills? Otherwise I'd just go with `let @* = expand('%') . ':' . line('.')`.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer I'm using lua because I'm using neovim rather than just vim.

Comment: VimScript works just fine in Neovim; you can use Lua of course, but don't *need* to use Lua, and for stuff like this it brings basically no advantages.